# jQuery html content of attribute data-x?

Tags: jquery, html, qtip

Is it possible to show in qtip2 html content from attribute data-x?

jquery-this code does not work with html in attribute data-x

```
$('.icon[data-x]').qtip({
    content: {
        attr: 'data-x'
    },
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center'
    }
});
```

html

```
<span class="icon" href="#" data-x="<strong>HTML</strong><br>content"></span>
```

Comment: What you have should work, assuming the browser doesn't mangle your span due to it being invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var $icon = $('.icon[x]');
$icon.qtip({
    content: $icon.attr('x')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.icon').qtip({ content: $('.icon').attr('x') });
```

If you are doing a custom attribute use data- as the prefix.  (ex: data-x)

If you change your attribute to data-x then use this code:

```
$('.icon').qtip({ content: $('.icon').attr('data-x') });
```

Comment: You're incorrect right there - when assessing the values of a `data-` attribute you still have to use `.attr('data-x')`, unless you are using `.data('x')`.

Comment: That is correct.  I should have been more clear, I was giving him a solution to the current requirements as well as giving him a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

codes dont work

problem is in parse HTML code (probably need to use .html() in jquery)

help link (but this code get content of span x and not span attribute x)
http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-use-hovered-element-s-own-html-for-qtip-content